# I have an attributes class where i set and get hero attributes and heroes class where i set heroes info and i want the game to process in my main

Tags: java

This is my class Attributes where setting and getting the variables is done

```
class Attributes{
    private int heroHp, heroDamage, heroArmor, currentHp, maxHp, rng, 
              playerAction;
    private String heroName;  
    private boolean isAlive, run;

    public void setName(String name){    
      heroName = name;
   }

   public String getName(){
      return heroName;
   }

   public void setHp(int hp){
      heroHp = hp;
      maxHp = heroHp;
   }

   public int getHp(){
      return heroHp;
   }

   public void setDamage(int damage){
      heroDamage = damage;
   }

   public int getDamage(){
      return heroDamage;
   }

   public void setArmor(int armor){
      heroArmor = armor;
   }

   public int getArmor(){
      return heroArmor;
   }

   public void setIsAlive(boolean isAlive){
      this.isAlive = isAlive;
   }

   public boolean getIsAlive(){
      return isAlive;
   }

   public void displayAttributes(){
      System.out.println("====================================");
      System.out.println("Hero name: " + heroName);
      System.out.println("Health: " + heroHp);
      System.out.println("Damage: " + heroDamage);
      System.out.println("Armor: " + heroArmor);
      System.out.println("====================================\n");
   }
```

This is my Heroes class

```
class Heroes{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Attributes slardar = new Attributes();
       Attributes phantomAssassin = new Attributes();
       slardar.setName("Slardar");
       slardar.setHp(115);
       slardar.setDamage(14);
       slardar.setArmor(6);
       slardar.setIsAlive(true);
       phantomAssassin.setName("Phantom Assasin");
       phantomAssassin.setHp(90);
       phantomAssassin.setDamage(17);
       phantomAssassin.setArmor(8);
       phantomAssassin.setIsAlive(true);
   }

}
```

How do i call or use those created objects in my main class? I tried but i really don't know. I also tried doing this

```
public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Attributes attribs = new Attributes();
       Heroes heroes = new Heroes();
       heroes.slardar.displayAttributes();
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid at the moment this question is too broad to answer - we don't know what any of the rest of your code looks like, or how you're trying to model the data. Please provide more of your code, and ask a very specific question - hopefully then we'll be able to help you more.

Comment: Thank you sir, i edited my question i hope it's understandable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having 2 main methods please try to use only one. As per your Main class heroes.slardar().displayAttributes(); says slardar() is a static method in Hero class , which is not present there. 
Instead you can code like this :

```
class Heroes {

    public static Attributes getSlardar() {

        Attributes  slardar = new Attributes();

        slardar.setName("Slardar");

        slardar.setHp(115);

        slardar.setDamage(14);

        slardar.setArmor(6);

        slardar.setIsAlive(true);

        return slardar;

    }

}

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        Attributes attribs = new Attributes();

        Heroes heroes = new Heroes();

        heroes.getSlardar().displayAttributes();

    }

}
```

Comment: Oh i get it now. Thank you so much sir :) I finally fixed my problem and also learned that it is possible to create the object inside a method. Thanks a lot!